# Is it possible to create an or-based MultiTrigger (or similar) for non-boolean properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

We have a control called SelectorSwitchedControl which uses a `Selector` to switch between child controls.  Think along the lines of a simplified Tab control but which uses a `ComboBox` or `ListBox` instead of tabs.

We're trying to build a trigger that says if there is more than one item in the list, we need to show the selector.

The only thing I can think of is to use two triggers, not one.  You make the selector visible by default in the control's template, then create two separate triggers to hide the selector: the first's condition testing for zero items, the second's testing for 1 item.  If either of those match, the selector will hide. If none do--i.e. there is two or more items--then it will remain visibile.

It works, but again, I'm wondering if there's any way to create this behavior using a single trigger, even if it's a MultiTrigger.  But a MultiTrigger is an 'And' test whereas we'd need an 'Or' test. Normally you could invert the logic to change a MultiTrigger to behave like an 'Or' but that would require the properties to be booleans themselves as there's no such thing as 'Not' conditions for the individual tests (i.e. you can't say 'property not equal to 0 and not equal to 1').

For the record, I know I could easily use converters and/or code-behind as a way to address this, but I'm wondering if there's a purely-XAML way to do this so this behavior could be a styled with no other code dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, create an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say `LessThanOrEqualConverter` which will take list count as input and return true or false based on the list count is greater than 0 or 1.

You can then have single trigger which will work both for 0 and 1.

**OR**

Simply have a converter `LengthToBoolConverter` and bind your Visibility to that converter. Converter will return `Visibility.Collapsed` if length is less than or equal to 1 and `Visibility.Visible` otherwise.

This way you don't need to worry about single trigger. Converter and binding will do that for you.

Comment: Yeah, I know about converters. But that's not a purely XAML approach, which is what I was wondering if it's possible.  The two-trigger approach is all I could come up with.  For the record, the reason I'm trying to avoid converters and go purely XAML is so this could be a purely-styled behavior with no other-code dependencies.

Comment: You have achieved as good as you can with pure XAML approach then i guess. There is no such `OR` operation in XAML. You have to resort back to converters for that.

Comment: Yeah... that's what I thought.  Shame MS doesn't add that to the spec.  Looks like it would be such a simple thing to add, but of course, there could be consequences I haven't considered.  Then again, we could always write our own OrMultiBinding too although technically as you said, we could do the same thing with a converter.

Comment: Yeah exactly. I don't think this will be a part of any future version of WPF specs as well. MS is too lazy in adding anything whose workaround is already there in form of converters.